# make remote backup copy of a file belonging to root

Tags: cron, rsync, root

I have created a somewhat clumsy solution and I really don't like it, I would like to improve it. Here is the problem:

I have a headless server that maintains a database that is stored within `/root/.local/somedir` and I want that file saved to a remote server. The main problem I am having is the fact it is a root account.

## My current solution:

#### under root:

- cron job every timeperiod* which hashes the file and saves that to a log
- the same cron job `rsync`s the file (if the hash has changed) to a user account on the same computer

#### under user account:

- cron job every other timeperiod and `rsync`s the file to a remote computer

* while testing, timeperiod is set to every 2 minutes, it will later be changed to daily or 6 hourly or some other period

#### the root cron:

```
#!/bin/sh
dt=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M');
d2=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M');
fn='/root/hash.log'
bk='/root/.local/share/file-to-backup'
b2="file-to-backup.$d2.bk"
hash_last=$(tail -1 hash.log | awk '{split($0,a," "); print a[3]}')
hash_now=$(md5sum $bk | awk '{split($0,a," "); print a[1]}')
if [ "$hash_now" != "$hash_last" ]; then
    echo "$dt $hash_now" >> $fn 
    rsync -og --chown=user:user $bk /home/user/$b2
elif [ "$1" = "force" ]; then
    rsync -og --chown=user:user $bk /home/user/$b2
fi
```

#### the user cron:

(the user has an SSH key setup)

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync --remove-source-files file-to* server:.
```

## the problem as I see it:

This works, but seems clumsy to me.

Ideally under the root user account where the file is actually located, I would like to make a backup remotely.

I think the problem is that I have a file that is under a root account that I want to have passwordless syncability to a remote server, I *think* that I shouldn't be creating private/public keys for a root account.

I'm not sure how I should best deal with this backup.

Comment: I have never given much thought to the fact the database that's running is running under the root account, mainly because the database is running on a VM that has specifically been created JUSt to run this database, and nothing else. The only reason there is a user account is so that i can log into it.

Comment: I am starting to think that even though it is a VM for this one purpose, I could create a user account just for the application and grant it copy privileges to copy the backup to the network? As mentioned in the OP, any suggestions appreciated

Comment: You're using `-og --chown=user:user`. That's first saying "preserve the owner and group" but then overwriting them with explicit values "user:user". You're also missing `-t` which is part of the metadata that `rsync` uses to shortcut unnecessary copying. (In general, unless you have a good reason, `rsync -a` should be your standard invocation.)

Answer (score 0):

> I think that I shouldn't be creating private/public keys for a root account.

Ask yourself, why is this under the root account in the first place?  Nearly all daemons on a traditional server run as a nonroot user.  If you're nervous about creating a *client* certificate for the root user (note this is completely distinct from allowing the certificate to log into the box, even if you do save it at the default location), you should be even more nervous about running your whatever as root.

Let's just skip past that question (though I do urge you to consider it), and move right along to this: there's really no reason *not* to generate client ssh certificates and rsync the file directly to the backup server as `root`.  You can save the rsa keys as any name you like; you'll be able to specify them when you run the rsync.  You won't be granting additional access *into* the server (though you already grant that of course, being as it's headless); instead you'll be allowing the key stored *on* the server (/root/.ssh is about as safe a place as any) to copy this file out as a *nonroot* server on the backup machine.

> This works, but seems clumsy to me.

Yeah, totally agree. `rsync` can tell whether files need to be synced, so basically everything you're doing there is enabling you to optionally copy that file to a nonroot location.  Mind you, there's no compelling reason you've mentioned that it's in `/root` to begin with; typically that directory is unreadable by others, so its subdirectories won't be accessible, but if this file *should* be acceptable by nonroot users, why not store it in a different directory whose permissions match the intended use - in the simplest case, allow the group to read the file and put the backup user in the group.   Or, have root do the backup.   Or, don't run as root in the first place.  It's your decision to own this file and directory path as root, only have it readable as root, but not want root to do the backing up, that makes this so clumsy.

Comment: I must have read your mind, I just created a comment specifically about this, it is on a VM that has been created explicitly just for running this database.